# Can I import multiple xsl files to another xsl file?

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am trying to import multiple xsl files from a specific folder to an xsl file, is there a way to import all the files in the folder with single tag?
like inporting folder or so..
Thanks
haranadh

Comment: Good question, +1 -- mainly because it will lead you to the correct answer that such a "feature" is not meaningful and useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in a single `import` statement.  The `href` must be a constant uri-reference.  See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#import) (same in [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#import)).

If you wanted to get creative, since a stylesheet is just an XML document, you could generate a transform with the necessary import statements, and import *that* stylesheet when needed with a single reference.

Comment: was just typing this answer ;-) Glad there is this organge bar telling you that someone was faster...

Answer (score 2):

As other people have stated, this isn't possible. However, no one pointed out that this isn't a "shortcoming".

**If such "feature" existed, it wouldn't be meaningful and useful**, because the order of the `<xsl:import>` instructions is really significant and therefore, *must* be specified manually.

Much more meaningful is *mass* `<xsl:include>` :)

Comment: On the other hand, no one said that it *was* a "shortcoming."  But good point nonetheless.

Comment: @harpo: If the people who answered were aware of this fact, they wouldn't have missed to state it and wouldn't advise how to dynamically create such a stylesheet. I consider such advice not well thought-over and actually quite wrong.

Comment: Dimitre, you are quite correct to point out (which I failed to), that a "wildcard" import feature would be unuseful in XSLT.  But if the OP can guarantee the correct order or knows that it is immaterial, then what is wrong with generating a list of imports?  Would it also be wrong if he wrote it by hand?

Comment: @harpo: Thanks, you are welcome. As to your question, if the programmer should specify the exact order of the imports from the directory, then he is doing the same work (and more) as specifying the ordered `<xsl:import>` instructions in his stylesheet. If he doesn't specify the individual order, there is no guarantee that the xsl files will be fetched in that order -- this is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that is not possible:

```
<xsl:import href="URI"/>
```

`xsl:import` takes a `URI` as value for its `href` attribute, so you can't specify a folder.